# freeform sending emails to control panel but not to my inbox

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am using freeform as a contact form, i have never had any problems with it before, when i submit an email from the developed form it returns as a submission in my freeform control panel, although the contact form submission is not reaching my inbox. Anyone any ideas why this is?

[image: freeform control panel]

Comment: Have you looked at the troubleshooting guide, specifically the email doesnt send section? http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/troubleshooting/

Comment: If the messages are being received in Freeform, it's very likely that either the settings or template code aren't specified to send the admin notification, or the server itself is not setup properly to send emails. Could you please update the question with your Freeform template code and some info about your hosting?

Answer (score 3):

The following is partly taken from the [Freeform troubleshooting guide](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/troubleshooting/), but here is a list of items to verify when email isn't being sent:

- Verify that your email address(es) is(are) correct.
- Check the **spam folder** of your email account
- Try sending email using the **Communicate Tool** in the CP? (CP => Tools => Communicate)
- Review your **template tag parameters** correctly (For example, the admin_notify="" and admin_notification_template="" parameters)
- Make sure you're using the **parameters for Freeform/Freeform Pro 4.x** and not 3.x (when using Freeform/Freeform Pro 4.x)
- Make sure you're using the parameters for Freeform 3.x and not Freeform/Freeform Pro 4.x (when using Freeform 3.x)
- Make sure there aren’t **malformed form fields or parameters** with curly/fancy/typographic quotes instead of straight quotes. Eg `“` vs `"`.
- Try sending **email using EE's native contact or tell-a-friend form**. See the [official EE documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/email/index.html)  for details on using these forms.
- Check your **server logs** for any errors.
- Verify that you are getting **redirected correctly after form submission**. If you are not being redirected correctly, have a look at your EE settings and .htaccess file for redirection issues that might then affect email.

Comment: What if the email submissions are coming through in one email (GMail) account but not another email (GMail) account?

Comment: Do both Gmail emails end with `@gmail.com`? Does the other Gmail account filter this kind of email (eg. blacklists based on a word or content in the notification email)? Does the email wind up in a spam folder?

Comment: Turned out to be incorrect settings in the MX Entries. The emails are ending up in the SPAM folder though - is there a way to prevent this from happening other than marking the emails as "not spam"?

Comment: Because `@gmail.com` emails are being sent form a server that isn't gmail.com (i.e. the sending server and the domain in the email address do not match), email applications can sometimes flag this kind of email as malicious/spam. This is a common problem, not only with gmail btw. Unfortunately whitelisting/blacklisting is often the way to deal with this.

Comment: You might also look into email services such as [Mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com) which take care of emailing for you, and are configured to avoid having email arrive in inboxes marked as spam/suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

Use the parameters admin_notify, admin_notification_template as well as notify_admin="yes".